# SwiftUI Vertical List Section header padding in iOS 15

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, ios15, xcode13

I have a `List` with `Sections` :

```
    List {
        ForEach((1...3), id: \.self) { _ in
            Section(
                header: Text("My Section")
                            .font(.system(.title3))
                            .fontWeight(.bold)
                            .foregroundColor(.primary),
                content: {
                    ForEach((1...5), id: \.self) { _ in
                        Text("My Row")
                    }
                }
            )
        }
    }
```

Here is the result on an iPhone 8 simulator with iOS 14.5:

[image: iPhone8_iOS14.5]

And here the result on an iPhone 8 simulator with iOS 15:

[image: iPhone8_iOS15]

I want iOS15 list to be equal to iOS14.5 one. I can remove horizontal padding by adding `.listStyle(PlainListStyle())` to the `List` but the header of the section still have different vertical padding.

[image: iPhone8_iOS15_PlainList]

**Is there a way to have the same vertical header padding as iOS14.5 ?**

Environment:

- iOS 15 RC
- XCode 13 RC

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Change list's style to `GroupedListStyle` using the `.listStyle()` modifier.

```
.listStyle(GroupedListStyle())
```

---

Header without gray backgrounnd

```
.listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

#### More info

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/liststyle

Comment: It answers my question thank you. But I see now that the header is not sticky, I will find another solution

Comment: @nelsonPARRILLA did you find another solution?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, what suited me the most was to add

```
if #available(iOS 15.0, *) {
    UITableView.appearance().sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

In AppDelegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` function

Comment: Is this for SwiftUI? And if yes, where do you put it?

Comment: @cseh_17 Yes it's for SwiftUi, I put it in AppDelegate -> didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Answer (score -2):

**Tested with SwiftUIIntrospect 0.10.0 on iOS 15 and 16**

Works with SwiftUI `List`

This modifier will remove padding for the header of UITableView on `iOS 15`

```
.introspect(.list(style: .plain), on: .iOS(.v15)) { tableView in
    tableView.sectionHeaderTopPadding = 0
}
```

This modifier will remove padding for the header of UICollectionView on `iOS 16`

```
.introspect(.list(style: .plain), on: .iOS(.v16)) { collectionView in
    let identifier = "ToolbarConfigured"
    guard collectionView.focusGroupIdentifier != identifier else { return }
    collectionView.focusGroupIdentifier = identifier
    
    var configuration = UICollectionLayoutListConfiguration(appearance: .plain)
    configuration.headerMode = .supplementary
    configuration.headerTopPadding = .zero
    configuration.showsSeparators = false
    configuration.backgroundColor = .clear
    let layout = UICollectionViewCompositionalLayout.list(using: configuration)
    collectionView.setCollectionViewLayout(layout, animated: false)
}
```

This code will remove grey background which appears under the header for both `iOS 15` and `iOS 16`. It needs UIScrollView which both UICollectionView and UITableView conform to. Works with single header which is always presented.

```
.introspect(.scrollView, on: .iOS(.v15, .v16)){ scrollView in
    guard let headerBG = scrollView.subviews
        .first(where: { $0.frame.height == 220 })?
        .subviews
        .first(where: { String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UISystemBackgroundView" }) else { return }
    guard headerBG.alpha != 0 else { return }
    headerBG.alpha = 0
}
```