# Unable to change iOS 15 SwiftUI List Section header padding

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list, ios15, xcode13

We are using SwiftUI and custom view for List Section's header.

But when compiling with Xcode13/iOS15 SDK, there seems to be extra left/right 20px + top/bottom 6px padding fixed in the header container view. I even created the bare minimum testing app, it seems unable to be customized.

This is not related to the newly introduced `sectionHeaderTopPadding`, so setting it to 0 doesn't work for me. I also tried `.environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 16)` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211298/swiftui-vertical-list-section-header-padding-in-ios-15), it also doesn't change the padding.

Here is snippet and screenshot:

```
        List {
            Section(header:
                Text("Big header")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .frame(height: 30)
                        .padding(0)
            ) {
                Text("Hello, world! 1")
                    .padding()
                Text("Hello, world! 2")
                    .padding()
                Text("Hello, world! 3")
                    .padding()
            }
        }
        .environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 1)
        .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
```

[image]
[image]

Thanks a lot for helping :) cheers

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Finally found the answer myself.

In iOS15, to remove padding for section header, you need to use `.listRowInsets(EdgeInsets())` just like list cell.

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this! So simple and works great.

Comment: Strange, the padding between the headers cannot be zero in iOS16 with XCode 14.3. It seams the backgorund color doesn't obey this.