# How to remove space above List in GroupedListStyle (need solution for ios 14)

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

i'm trying to create List with GroupedListStyle. But when i provide a section without header there is empty space above the section. How to remove that empty space?

```
List {
            Section(header: Text("Section 1")) {
                Text("List 1 - Item 1")
                Text("List 1 - Item 2")
                Text("List 1 - Item 3")
            }
            
            Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
                Text("List 2 - Item 1")
                Text("List 2 - Item 2")
                Text("List 2 - Item 3")
            }
        }
        .listStyle(.grouped)
```

I tried to provide negative padding. It working fine with ios 16+ devices. But in iOS 15 and iOS 14 negative padding is not taken.
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SwiftUI Vertical List Section header padding in iOS 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69211298/swiftui-vertical-list-section-header-padding-in-ios-15)

Comment: Hi @lazarevzubov, thank you for the suggestion. But I need style exactly same as grouped except the top padding.

Comment: How about this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/69394360/7016052 I know it's messing with UIKit again, but might work.

Comment: Nope, other part of my project have UIKit elements. So,i can't change the behaviour of UIKit elements

Comment: From iOS 17 you can use [`contentMargins(_:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/contentmargins(_:for:))

Answer (score 2):

✅ This should work fine:

```
List {
    Section(
        header: Color.clear.frame(height: 0).listRowInsets(.init()) // <-- 1
    ) {
        Text("List 1 - Item 1")
        Text("List 1 - Item 2")
        Text("List 1 - Item 3")
    }
    
    Section(header: Text("Section 2")) {
        Text("List 2 - Item 1")
        Text("List 2 - Item 2")
        Text("List 2 - Item 3")
    }
}
.listStyle(.grouped)
.environment(\.defaultMinListHeaderHeight, 0.1) // <-- 2
```